# MemoryWriter Helper class

Tags: c++, beginner, memory-management, windows

I have created this memory writer helper to ease the write into memory process and I want your suggestions regarding it. I am very new to C++ but have 6 years knowledge of .NET languages like VB and C#.

```
#include <wtypes.h>

class MemoryWriter {
private:
    USHORT _currentIndex;
    LPVOID _targetAddress;
    template<typename T>
    static void editMemory(DWORD address, T data)
    {
        DWORD oldProtection;
        VirtualProtect((LPVOID)address, sizeof(T), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtection);
        *((T*)address) = data;
        VirtualProtect((LPVOID)address, sizeof(T), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, NULL);
    }
public:
    MemoryWriter(DWORD address) {
        _currentIndex = 0;
        _targetAddress = (LPVOID)address;
    }
    template<typename T>
    void write(T data)
    {
        editMemory<T>(((DWORD)_targetAddress + _currentIndex), data);
        _currentIndex += sizeof(T);
    }
    template<typename T>
    void write(LPVOID address, T data)
    {
        editMemory<T>((DWORD)address, data);
        _currentIndex = (DWORD)address;
    }
    void reset(LPVOID newAddress = NULL)
    {
        _currentIndex = 0;

        if (newAddress)
            _targetAddress = newAddress;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

A general physical layout guideline: Put all `public` members, functions as well as variables, first, followed by `protected` members, and `private` members at the end. You want users to see `public` members first, followed by `protected` members. Hopefully, they don't have to see `private` members at all.

I added white spaces around functions to make them more readable.

```
class MemoryWriter {

   public:

      MemoryWriter(DWORD address) {
         _currentIndex = 0;
         _targetAddress = (LPVOID)address;
      }

      template<typename T>
         void write(T data)
         {
            editMemory<T>(((DWORD)_targetAddress + _currentIndex), data);
            _currentIndex += sizeof(T);
         }

      template<typename T>
         void write(LPVOID address, T data)
         {
            editMemory<T>((DWORD)address, data);
            _currentIndex = (DWORD)address;
         }

      void reset(LPVOID newAddress = NULL)
      {
         _currentIndex = 0;

         if (newAddress)
            _targetAddress = newAddress;
      }

   protected:

   private:

      USHORT _currentIndex;
      LPVOID _targetAddress;

      template<typename T>
         static void editMemory(DWORD address, T data)
         {
            DWORD oldProtection;
            VirtualProtect((LPVOID)address, sizeof(T), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtection);
            *((T*)address) = data;
            VirtualProtect((LPVOID)address, sizeof(T), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, NULL);
         }
};
```